# How to control the interval of time between triggering of mousewheel event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently writing a website for a movie making company, which shows their different movies in full-screen.
I put each video in a list, and wrote a function that takes the user to the next video everytime a mousewheel event is triggered. The problem is that when the user is mousewheeling with a trackpad, it triggers multiple events at once, so I figured, I just had to set an interval between each triggering, depending on a variable "animating" that would be either true or false.

So here's my code :

```
let animating = false


$(window).bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0 && actuallyPlaying === false && animating === false) {
        animating = true;
        goToPreviousVideo();
        setInterval(function () {
            animating = false
        }, 2000)
    }
    else {
        if (actuallyPlaying === false && animating === false) {
            animating = true;
            goToNextVideo();
            setInterval(function () {
                animating = false
            }, 2000)
        };
    }
});
```

And this piece of code works fine, but only for a few video "swipes". I noticed that after two or three times, this function stops working, and many events get triggered at the same time, which results in skipping all the videos and going from the top of the page straight to the bottom.

Do you guys have any idea why this isn't working ?

I'm also adding the code of goToNextVideo() and goToPreviousVideo() in case the problem is with them :

```
let i = 1 // 
const goToNextVideo = function () {
    if (i === 4) { // because I've got 4 videos
       return;
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(`.video-${i + 1}`).offset().top
        }, 500);
        $(`.video-${i + 1}`).get(0).play();
        i += 1
        $(`.video-${i - 1}`).get(0).pause();
        
        
    }
};

const goToPreviousVideo = function () {
    if (i === 1) {
        return
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(`.video-${i - 1}`).offset().top
        }, 500);
        $(`.video-${i}`).get(0).pause();
        i -= 1
        $(`.video-${i}`).get(0).play();

    }
    
};
```

Thanks for your help !

Wish you all a great day

Comment: You can use a debounce functionality, or create a bucket to add the event and only  call a new event if the bucket is empty.

Comment: As comment above, seems you want to `debounce` the wheel event Debounce works when your code receives multiple events - it waits until no more events are incoming, then fires the "real" event.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know about debounce ! I used @Frenchy solution bellow which works perfectly fine, but I'm gonna look for the debounce documentation. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Looks like that would also be an issue even with debouce, so a worth answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its seems your error is coming from the fact you dont clear the setInterval,

```
let animating = -1;


$(window).bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0 && actuallyPlaying === false && animating < 0) {
        animating = setInterval(function () {
            clearInterval(animating);
            animating = -1;
        }, 2000)
        goToPreviousVideo();

    }
    else {
        if (actuallyPlaying === false && animating < 0) {
            animating = setInterval(function () {
                clearInterval(animating);
                animating = -1;
            }, 2000)
            goToNextVideo();

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: yes if you dont clear it repeats indefinitly..glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand where the problem is lying but
I have a cleaner and better approach to doing this Please tell if it works

```
var lastVideoChangeAnimation = Date.now()-2001;

$(window).bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0 && actuallyPlaying === false && Date.now()-lastAlertTime>2000) {
        lastVideoChangeAnimation = Date.now();
        goToPreviousVideo();
    }
    else if (actuallyPlaying === false && Date.now()-lastAlertTime>2000) {
        lastVideoChangeAnimation = Date.now();
        goToNextVideo();
    };
});
```

THERE CAN ALSO BE A PROBLEM THAT THERE OCCURS SOME SORT OF ERROR AND YOUR CODE STOPS EXECUTING.
SO JUST CHECK IF THE CONSOLE IS GIVING SOME ERROR WITH POINTING TOWARDS THE FILE WHERE THESE TWO CODES ARE SAVED.

Also please tell in the comment that did it worked